# MVC3 SelectedValue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, selectedvalue

In my model:

```
public SelectList QuestionGroupSelectList { get; set; }

------
List<QuestionGroup> questionGroupList = questionGroupRepository.GetQuestionGroup_BySurveyId(survey.Id);

Dictionary<int, string> questionGroupDictionary = questionGroupList.ToDictionary(l => l.Id, l => l.Name);

QuestionGroupSelectList = new SelectList(questionGroupDictionary, "key", "value", questionGroupId);





---------------------------------------
In view:
@Html.DropDownList("QuestionGroupSelectList", Model.QuestionGroupSelectList, "Choose Here")
```

When i debug i get 2 items in QuestionGroupSelectList (one with Id 30 and one with Id 35), and it says that the selectedValue is 35 (questionGroupId = 35)

But the selectedvalue does not work in the view, any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you accessing your repository in the model and not the controller?

Comment: Ive heard that your should keep your controllers as small as possible. Not sure if it true tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a different property to bind your dropdownlist value to. Also you should use view models and strongly typed helpers, like this:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int QuestionGroupId { get; set; }
    public SelectList QuestionGroupSelectList { get; set; }
}
```

then you could have a controller action which populates this view model and passes it to the view:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{ 
    // This collection could come from anywhere 
    // normally you will query a repository here to fetch those values
    var values = new[] 
    {
        new { Key = "1", Value = "item 1" },
        new { Key = "2", Value = "item 2" },
        new { Key = "3", Value = "item 3" },
    }

    var model = new MyViewModel
    {
        // preselect the second value
        QuestionGroupId = 2,
        QuestionGroupSelectList = new SelectList(values, "Key", "Value")
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

and finally in your view:

```
@model MyViewModel

@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.QuestionGroupId, 
    Model.QuestionGroupSelectList, 
    "Choose Here"
)
```